# Why isn't there any output?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

```
$results = db_query("select nid from {taxonomy_index} where tid = :tid", array(':tid' => arg(2)));
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $node = node_load($result->nid);
  echo $node->title;
}
```

I put the code in page--taxonomy.tpl.php, but there is no result. Why?

The output of `print_r($results)` is the following one.

```
DatabaseStatementBase Object
(
    [dbh] => DatabaseConnection_mysql Object
        (
            [shutdownRegistered:protected] => 
            [target:protected] => default
            [key:protected] => default
            [logger:protected] => 
            [transactionLayers:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [driverClasses:protected] => Array
                (
                    [SelectQuery] => SelectQuery
                )

            [statementClass:protected] => DatabaseStatementBase
            [transactionSupport:protected] => 1
            [transactionalDDLSupport:protected] => 
            [temporaryNameIndex:protected] => 0
            [connectionOptions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [database] => 
                    [username] => 
                    [password] => 
                    [host] => 
                    [port] => 
                    [driver] => 
                    [prefix] => Array
                        (
                            [default] => 
                        )

                )

            [schema:protected] => 
            [prefixes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [default] => 
                )

            [prefixSearch:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {
                    [1] => }
                )

            [prefixReplace:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

        )

    [queryString] => select nid from taxonomy_index where tid = :tid
```

Comment: Whats the output for `$results->rowCount()` ?

Comment: i put print_r($results) to the question. there is no output.werid thing

Comment: what's use of the table taxonomy_index?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737839/how-to-change-the-sql-command-into-drupal-7/13744389#13744389  Don't post across sites

Comment: Please don't put queries in your templates, it may cause mental harm yourself and other developers. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Please confirm you got any value from arg(2) which is equivalent to term id(tid) .*

Try this code

```
$result = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't')
  ->fields('t')
  ->condition('tid', arg(2), '=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();

$node = node_load($result->nid);

print_r($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy_index database table just contains a list of the nodes using a taxonomy term, not that taxonomy term, and any of its child terms (or its parent terms). If there isn't any node that is using a taxonomy term, the code you wrote doesn't print anything.

If you want to get a list of node using a taxonomy term, or its child terms, you could use code similar to the following one.

```
$tid = arg(2);
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 'h.tid = t.tid');
$query->addField('t', 'tid');
$query->condition(
  db_or()
    ->condition('h.parent', $tid)
    ->condition('t.tid', $tid)
);
$query->addTag('term_access');
$query->orderBy('t.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.name');
$tids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

$nids = db_query("select nid from {taxonomy_index} where tid IN :tids", array(':tids' => $tids))->fetchCol();

$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

The other reasons that could cause the code not to print anything are:

- The taxonomy_index table is empty for some reasons, including the fact the Drupal variable taxonomy_maintain_index_table is not set to `TRUE`. Check what `variable_get('taxonomy_maintain_index_table')` returns; if it returns `FALSE` (or an equivalent value), that would explain why the table is not populated.
- The value you are using as taxonomy term ID is not a taxonomy term ID.
- There isn't any node using the taxonomy term for which you have the ID.